# How can set Project Collection Build Service identity to be a Contributor on my Azure artifacts feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get the Azure Pipelines to publish a nuget package to my project's private Artifacts feed.

The first step per [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-a-package) is set Project Collection Build Service identity to be a Contributor on your feed.

I followed the link and went to Artifacts->My feed->Feed Settings->Permissions and I am not able to change anything about the build user.[image]

I noticed build service users are org wide so I went to Org settings->Users but that user doesn't show up there at all. In fact I can't find any mention of this build user anywhere but the page in the screen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the Project Collection Build Service identity and then add it as contributor.

[image]

Project Collection Build Service identity is an internal identity generated by DevOps not users that invited from outside. It can't be found in organization settings >> users. You could search the Project Collection Build Service identity in **organization settings >> permission >> users**.

[image]